# Match SQL Id's and get and apply the matching value

Tags: php, sql, database

I'm working on an add-on for a script. It's an old add-on written by someone else I used to know but then just left dead. In my interests of learning more php/sql, I've been working on it. Pretty much, it's a support ticket system.

Right now, there's a file which holds all convenient DB functions when they need to be called. I'm making a page that lists all of the tickets, and their status (New, Answered, so on...), but I'd like to add the name of the Department it was sent to. Admins can make departments, and then users can pick one of these departments when making a ticket. My problem is, however, that the person who left the code never really merged departments with tickets. Here's the ticket code I currently have:

```
static function ticket_list() {
    return OW::getDbo()->queryForList("SELECT id,category_id,subject,requested_deletion,department_id,updated,status FROM ".SupportCenterDB::table_ticket()." ORDER BY updated DESC;");
}
```

"department_id" is the key factor here. There's a DB table for departments, and a call for "department_get" which is as follows:

```
static function department_get($id) {
        $d=OW::getDbo();
        $res=$d->queryForList("SELECT * FROM ".SupportCenterDB::table_department()." WHERE id='".$d->escapeString($id)."';");
        return $res[0];
    }
```

So, I call all the tickets as so:

```
$tickets_q=SupportCenterDB::ticket_list();

        $tickets=array();

        foreach($tickets_q as $data) {

            array_push($tickets,array(

                "text"=>$data["subject"],

                "updated"=>$data["updated"],

                "department"=>$data["department_id"],

                "status"=>$this->get_ticket_status($data),

                //"url_view"=>"/settings/tickets/view/${data["id"]}",

                "url_view"=>OW::getRouter()->urlForRoute("supportcenter-manage-tickets-view",array("id"=>$data["id"])),

                "url_delete"=>OW::getRouter()->urlForRoute("supportcenter-manage-tickets-delete",array("id"=>$data["id"])),

                "request_deletion"=>$data["requested_deletion"],

            ));


        }


        $this->assign("items",$tickets);
```

This simply only shows the actual id of the selected department when I have the value displayed on the table. In this case, the department's text value is "Support" but the ID is "1". This code shows the department as the id, so as "1". I want to get it so the received $data of the department_id will match with the rest of my Department tables, so that I can actually display the Department text.

Basically, I want to get the value of department_id from each $tickets_q, and have the id match with the text of the corresponding department, so it displays the actual name and not the ID number.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not really in my field of expertise, but the question is well asked. Welcome to SatckOverflow Jake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is an [Inner Join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp). You can modify your original query to accomplish this in one statement. This also assumes you don't need the `department_id`, just the `department_name`. If you do need it, add it back into your list of fields to fetch.

```
static function ticket_list() {
    $table_ticket = SupportCenterDB::table_ticket();
    return OW::getDbo()->queryForList("SELECT id, category_id, subject, 
            requested_deletion, table_departments.text, updated, status FROM {$table_ticket}
            JOIN table_departments ON table_departments.id = {$table_ticket}.department_id
            ORDER BY updated DESC;");
}
```

Note: You should really look into using a prepared statement for the SQL query, that way you're not passing in a parameter directly into your select statement, even if it is defined right above it.

Update:
`"department"=>$data["department_id"]` needs to become `"department"=>$data["text"]`. To be cleaner, you could give the field an alias so you know what you're actually pulling.

`SELECT id, category_id, ..., table_departments.text AS department_name, updated, status...`

And then the line above becomes `"department"=>$data["department_name"]`.

Comment: Thanks, this is pointing me in the right direction, I believe. The table for departments is called with "table_departments" and simply consists of the primary ID "id" (the department id) and "text" (the department name). I'm having trouble understanding where tickets are correctly getting the right department ID included with them, but how to make that ID be read as it's 'text' (name) value instead of it's id.

Comment: @JakeBrunton I updated my answer according to the table name and fields. According to your original code, there is a `department_id` field for every entry in `table_tickets`. That seems to be a foreign key referencing the `id` field in `table_departments`. When you join one table onto another one, you are usually matching values, in this case the `department_id` and the primary key `id`. Once joined, you now have access to department data on all matching entries.

Comment: Steve, thanks for  your help. I think I've got most of it the way it needs to be. My last problem with it is the `JOIN departments` I have no "departments" table but rather table_department as is called the same way you did with table_ticket - as a variable. When I replaced that bit with `JOIN {$table_ticket}.department_id` I get a SELECT denied error.

Comment: Here's the altercation to it so far:
`static function ticket_list() {
    $table_ticket = SupportCenterDB::table_ticket();
 $dp = SupportCenterDB::table_department();
    return OW::getDbo()->queryForList("SELECT {$table_ticket}.id, category_id, subject, 
            requested_deletion, {$dp}.text, department_id, updated, status FROM {$table_ticket}
            JOIN {$table_ticket}.department_id ON {$dp}.id = {$table_ticket}.department_id
            ORDER BY updated DESC;");
}`

Comment: @JakeBrunton Your JOIN needs to be `JOIN {$dp} ON {$dp}.id = {$table_ticket}.department_id`.

Comment: This is still showing the corresponding result as the id number, not the text value. Is it a problem with my array_push now?

Comment: Nevermind, had to change my `$data["department_id"]` to `$data["text"]` Thanks for your help!